# how to suspend execution in java using thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

i have created a wizard programatically. it contain 3 panels. the second one is devicePane and third one is detailsPane. the third panel consist of a progress bar. i want my program to start a function `process()` after displaying the third panel? is it possible using thread?

```
else if(ParserMainDlg.this.POSITION==1){
    if(sqlConnectionPane.executeProcess()==true){    
        devicePane.setDeviceList();                             
         ParserMainDlg.this.POSITION++;
         fireStateChanged(oldValue);
    }
}
else if(ParserMainDlg.this.POSITION==2){
    System.out.println("position:"+ParserMainDlg.this.POSITION);
    if(devicePane.executeProcess()==true){
         ParserMainDlg.this.POSITION++;
         fireStateChanged(oldValue);    
    }
```

I want `sqlConnectionPane.executeProcess()` to call a function which starts executing after displaying the devicePane Panel?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: If you display the devicePanel in a JOptionPane or other modal dialog, you could always start execution of your process in the code immediately afterwards. Otherwise you'll have to use a listener of some type.

Comment: Lookup an option to integrate `SwingWorker`. Nobody knows how long it will be `sqlConnectionPane.executeProcess()`

Answer (score 1):

You can definitly use a thread to execute your task, this is the preferred way of handling a long running task.

You have multiple options here. All options include making a callback to your wizard, to update the progressbar.

You can make your own task class wich does exactly this, or you can use the existing [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). "SwingWorker itself is an abstract class; you must define a subclass in order to create a SwingWorker object; anonymous inner classes are often useful for creating very simple SwingWorker objects."

Using the swing worker we just learned about you can use something like this:

```
SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> backgroundWork = new SwingWorker<Integer, Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected final Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                this.publish(i);
            }

            return 60;
        }

        @Override
        protected final void process(final List<Integer> chunks) {
            progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(0));
        }

    };

    backgroundWork.execute();
```

Note that you will have to break your task down into smaller parts to actually be able to display progress.

Comment: +1 except one point: you'll probably want to update your progressBar to the _last_ of the chunks, not the first

Comment: there is always only 1 item in the list of integers because we publish only 1 integer per iteration :) it doesnt really matter if you use the first or last.

it might also be worth noting that the progressBar needs to be updated on the edt!

Comment: "For performance purposes all these invocations are coalesced into one invocation with concatenated arguments.

For example:

 publish("1");
 publish("2", "3");
 publish("4", "5", "6");
 
might result in:
 process("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")"


you are correct sir, i stand corrected!